# Heteroscedasticity

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, weights, exponential-smoothing

I am trying to build a regression model to explain variations in mortgage volumes using variations in different mortgage rates. To account for the drastic change in macroeconomic environment: from near zero rates to positive rates, I have used a weight variable to give more weight to the more recent observations relative to the older data. This as expected, is helping the model perform better than an unweighted model on accurately predicting more recent observations. However, the problem is the model is failing the test for homoscedasticity. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated. Can provide more details on demand.

Comment: can you please upload a plot of your residuals vs predictions? I personally find the tests for heteroscedasticity to be too strong. If you have a lot of points they'll always ping. If your plot looks fine it should be ok. Use/compare with robust standard errors to be sure.

Comment: Also your comments about predictions takes things in a different direction. If you are predicting instead of inferring who cares if heteroscedasticity fails. That doesn't automatically make things biased, and even if they were biased that doesn't automatically make it less predictive. Het-sce largely affects the estimation of your standard errors.